# Where to Calibration data

Tags: xorg, touch-screen

where can I find calibration data/setting stored in Ubuntu.

Comment: Did you see the "Retrieving Calibration Values from NVRAM / Pre-Calibration" section?

Comment: How can I see content of monitor NVRAM?

Comment: What is "monitor NVRAM"?

Comment: In the documentation it is mentioned "A valid calibration must exist in the monitor NVRAM".

Comment: Isn't the device a "monitor"? I think they meant "the NVRAM included in the monitor", otherwise I can't make sense of it.